# Flush output buffer in Apache/Nginx setup

Tags: php, nginx, output-buffering

I would like to have page content for a web page I am developing appear on screen as it is downloaded. In my test/development environment this works as expected using the PHP flush() command.

However, my production setup (WPEngine) uses an Nginx proxy in front of Apache and flush() no longer works (nor do any of the other output buffering commands). I have been able to get the desired behaviour by deliberately filling up the buffer when I want to flush by sending 4k worth of whitespace.

However, that feels like a hack and the page in question needs to be flushed 100 times or more so this adds a considerable amount to the total data downloaded.

Is there a way to signal to Nginx to flush the buffer (or not buffer at all) by sending control characters and/or setting HTTP headers so I can avoid sending otherwise unnecessary whitespace?

Since WPEngine is a managed hosting environment, I am not able to make any changes to the server setup. So, for example, turning off Nginx buffering by adding a directive to the nginx server config is not an option.

The way I am currently doing this is as follows:-

```
<?php
//turn off server content compression for this page
header('Content-Encoding: none;');

//turn off PHP output buffering
ob_end_flush();

//make padding to fill buffer
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096*8);

$start = time();

do
{
    printf( 'Time: %s secs<br>', time() - $start );
    echo $buffer;
    sleep(1);
} while( (time() - $start) < 10 );
?>
```

Comment: great! the trick is the ob_end_flush() at the start of file + setting `fastcgi_buffering off;` in nginx conf (if you use PHP-FPM). Don't need to overflow the buffer, remove that, just add a flush() after printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn off buffering in nginx:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Reference: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_buffering

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do this without updating the server's Nginx config?

Comment: Have you read the docs on the link I provided? A quote from it: _Buffering can also be enabled or disabled by passing “yes” or “no” in the “X-Accel-Buffering” response header field._

Comment: Yes, but <blush> I completely missed that bit. Unfortunately, though, adding `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no;');` doesn't seem to turn buffering off, which suggests that WPEngine uses `proxy_ignore_headers` to prohibit that :-(

Comment: Try without ";" at the end of `no`, I mean: `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');`

Comment: The `;` made no difference on that count or with other headers which are working. WPEngine claims they aren't preventing it with `proxy_ignore_headers`, but when I `cURL --head` to a test page while other headers I set come through fine, the `X-Accel-Buffering` header is absent.

Comment: Maybe they use gzip compression (it also buffers response)? Try to check without the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: Double <blush>... I re-ran my test script and it now works as expected. I had forgotten to reinsert `flush()` instead of `echo $buffer;`. The `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');` was all that was needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

While there's already an accepted answer that's somewhat correct, it's worth noting that if you're using php-fpm, `fastcgi_buffering` is also an issue.

The documentation is unclear, but emitting the `X-Accel-Buffering: no` header in your response will disable `fastcgi_buffering`, **only in >= nginx 1.5.6**. The header actually seems to affect both `proxy_buffering` and `fastcgi_buffering`, which [isn't clear from the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering).

Since most distros are still running nginx 1.4 series, and a lot of people are using php-fpm, this is a potential tripping point (i.e. it hung me up for an hour).

Comment: Adding header `X-Accel-Buffering: no` works like a charm when you want to disable buffering for a specific request.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an nginx issue, use this in the location that is being buffered

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
```

If you need help knowing where exactly you need to put that then share your nginx config file.

Comment: Nginx in front of Apache doesn't use fastcgi at all.